# Read INI file and check checkbox

Tags: checkbox, vbscript, ini, checked

I have written an application that reads an INI file using

```
wAccessDeniedMsg.Text = ReadIni(File, Options, AccessDeniedMsg, "")
```

Now this fills a textbox with a message.

But I also want to have a checkbox checked when the value is 1.

So I wrote:

```
ReadIni(File, Options, AccessDeniedEnabled, "")
        If AccessDeniedEnabled = "1" Then
            wAccessDeniedEnabled.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        End If
```

But this does not enable my checkbox.

I searched on several sites and forum but I could not get this to work.

Do you have any idea how I can get the checkbox set to Checked when the value is 1?

Comment: What checkbox? Where? You need to provide a lot more context for anyone to even try to answer the question.

Comment: What context is the vbscript used in? asp? hta? You need to provide more details.